# Receiving segmentation fault error while reading file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, parsing, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read content from a .txt file, but I keep running into the following error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I also try to print the content of each line of the, but it does not print all the content. It will stop half way. My file looks something like this:

```
1,30,226
1,2,1003
1,32,153
1,4,166
1,5,212
2,4,1075
2,26,456
2,50,308
3,16,186
3,13,577
3,15,190
3,41,79
3,31,511
4,5,455
4,32,215
4,30,161
4,28,1391
5,51,105
5,9,191
6,52,605
6,32,829
6,51,2116
7,18,432
7,38,165
7,8,987
8,28,511
8,46,361
9,34,476
9,47,214
9,51,292
9,10,1341
10,11,792
10,15,20
10,16,248
10,41,374
11,46,523
11,35,466
11,35,386
12,44,135
12,28,246
12,4,933
12,26,789
12,50,310
12,13,1132
13,41,580
13,35,320
13,35,328
14,34,3939
14,19,5313
15,44,314
15,17,413
16,15,101
16,31,321
17,18,1014
17,20,502
17,50,432
18,33,146
18,22,113
19,36,5131
19,48,5451
20,44,249
20,46,190
20,21,1092
20,22,1231
21,49,446
21,22,2341
21,29,892
22,27,902
22,49,169
22,50,104
22,23,421
23,24,275
23,53,486
23,39,439
24,43,124
24,48,182
24,29,328
25,37,275
25,36,365
26,44,413
27,33,235
27,49,282
27,21,159
28,32,463
28,25,1920
29,40,80
30,51,401
30,29,1080
31,50,388
31,32,1901
32,34,101
32,53,1311
32,24,1531
33,49,84
33,32,1343
34,14,3548
34,52,147
35,43,518
36,37,642
36,24,962
36,42,635
36,40,115
36,48,271
37,45,174
37,53,777
38,52,371
39,53,520
39,40,133
40,41,140
40,42,95
41,48,895
41,42,2093
42,43,50
42,48,232
43,48,168
44,32,882
44,51,436
45,52,115
46,53,335
47,17,165
47,46,795
47,9,212
48,51,2751
48,50,133
48,52,232
51,18,486
52,51,2095
49,50,275
49,51,1335
49,53,2328
50,11,795
50,52,2095
51,15,201
51,16,248
52,41,373
52,19,4869
53,52,2084
53,26,1243
53,51,2343
36,43,519
15,32,643
46,24,962
46,42,633
38,40,113
26,48,222
16,19,3431
27,40,123
35,43,1131
25,45,220
15,11,341
25,42,1232
```

There are no spaces, just numbers separated by commas. Why can I not read till the end of the file? I am trying to place checks to see if I hit the end of the file, but I am not sure why I run into a segmentation fault earlier than this. How do I read all the way till the end of a text file with 3 numbers on each line, all separated by commas? The first argument passed in is the name of the file, and the second argument passed in is the number of nodes (vertices) in the graph I want to create. These are absolutely valid inputs, and I am sure that is not the cause of the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;

#include "Graph.h"
#include "Dijkstra.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(argv[1]);

    Graph g(stoi(argv[2])); // Create the graph

    int src, dest, weight;
    string line, tempString1, tempString2, tempString3;

    while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        getline(ss, tempString1, ',');
        src = stoi(tempString1);
        getline(ss, tempString2, ',');
        dest = stoi(tempString2);
        getline(ss, tempString3, ',');
        weight = stoi(tempString3);
        g.addEdge(src, dest, weight);
        cout << src << " " << dest << " " << weight << endl;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Graph code:

```
class Graph {
    private:
        int n; // Number of vertices
        // Pointer to adjacency list, contains the vertex to point to and its weight
        list<pair<int, int>> *adj; 
    
    public:
        // Constructor
        Graph(int n) {
            n = n;
            adj = new list<pair<int, int>>[n]; // Create an adjacency list of size n
        }

        // Add a weighted edge to the graph
        void addEdge(int src, int dest, int weight) {
            adj[src].push_back(make_pair(dest, weight));
        }
```

Comment: What debugger do you have access to? I'm asking so we can get visibility on what line is causing the seg fault.

Comment: Use a debugger (preferably with address sanitizer) to figure out where the code is crashing and what the state of the program is before it crashes. It's probably somewhere in the graph code.

Comment: Also, make sure that you're successfully opening the file. `ifstream` has an `operator bool()` function that allows you to idiomatically check for a valid open stream with `if (inputFile) { ...success case... } else { ...failure case... };`

Comment: @JohnFilleau, That one's at least covered by the loop condition. An error opening the file will cause the first read to fail and skip the loop entirely.

Comment: ok the error lies in graph.h, this code works fine if the 2 lines that use it are commented out, can we see it please

Comment: did you pass 2 args to this program? that Graph line needs the second arg, you should add a check for argc == 3

Comment: Hi all, I've added the graph code here with the function `addEdges`. @JohnFilleau I'm currently trying to step through the VSCode Debugger, @pm100 yes I used 2 arguments!

Comment: What command line options are you passing in?

Comment: this fails if argv[2] is too small. WHat did you pass as args

Comment: @JohnFilleau, for my specific example, I pass in `./main graphs/graph_1.txt 53`. 53 represents 53 vertices.

Comment: can we have the input file please, I thought your sample output was the input :-(

Comment: try saying 54 instead of 53, if you highest vertex number is 53 then you needs a vector of size 54

Comment: [Clang gives a warning](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6nov1qdoT). There's also no need to use a pointer to a list, you can have the list directly. You're making an array of lists, but the comment suggests otherwise, which wouldn't compile without the pointer.

Comment: also what do you think this line does `n = n;` in graph.h

Comment: @pm100 I've updated it to include my entire list

Comment: @pm100 You are right, instead of using 53 I used 54 and I did not receive a segmentation fault at all

Comment: did you see my comment about `n=n` in graph.h , thats very wrong

Comment: I hope you understand why 54 works but 53 does not

Comment: and do what @chris said, dont `new` the list, its not needed and now you have to worrry about deleting it and it will be marginally slower

Comment: @pm100, yes I understood your point. I also changed `n = n` to be `vertex_count = n`. I changed the name of the private variable from `n` to `vertex_count` as well. I realize my mistake there as well, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You could have done `Graph(int n) : n{n} {` however renaming the class member `n` to `vertex_count` good for readability